# Making a filter to show/hide the elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use a filtering function in my webpage. When a button is clicked, it hides the associated elements and fades itself. Once it's clicked again, it brings those elements back and restores its color.

What I want to do is to add two additional buttons: "Show all" and "Hide all". I want them to show/hide all elements and also fade/restore all the button colors upon click.

First I made an `onclick` event handler for these two buttons, but it didn't work properly. I think I have to combine everything in the same onload event, and that's where I got stuck. Could you please help me to modify my js to achieve my goal?

Snippet:

```js
for (let button of document.querySelectorAll(".filterbutton")) {
  button.addEventListener("click", filter);
}

let filters = new Set;

function toggleDisplay(selector, display) {
  let elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  for (let elem of elems) {
    elem.style.display = display;
  }
}

function filter() {
  let filterSelector = this.dataset.filter;
  let show = filters.delete(filterSelector);
  this.style.color = show ? "" : "rgb(200,200,200)";
  if (!show) {
    filters.add(filterSelector); // toggle this filter
  } else {
    toggleDisplay(filterSelector, "");
  }
  if (filters.size) {
    toggleDisplay([...filters].join(","), "none");
  }
}
```

```css
.filterbutton,
.showallbutton,
.hideallbutton {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer
}

.group a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="filter">
  <div class="filterbutton" data-filter=".filter01">Filter 01</div>
  <div class="filterbutton" data-filter=".filter02">Filter 02</div>
  <div class="filterbutton" data-filter=".filter03">Filter 03</div>
</div>

<div class="group">
  <a class="filter01 filter02 filter03">This element has filter01, filter02 and filter03</a>
  <a class="filter01 filter02">This element has filter01 and filter02</a>
  <a class="filter01 filter03">This element has filter01 and filter03</a>
  <a class="filter02 filter03">This element has filter02 and filter03</a>
  <a class="filter01">This element has filter01 only</a>
  <a class="filter02">This element has filter02 only</a>
  <a class="filter03">This element has filter03 only</a>
</div>

<div class="show-hide">
  <div class="showallbutton">Show all</div>
  <div class="hideallbutton">Hide all</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't have click handlers for `.showallbutton` or `.hideallbutton` in your code. Please share that as well of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always delegate

Here I delegate from document; if you can find a closer container, use that instead

I also removed the dot from the `data-filter=".` <<<

Lastly I made the color change a class.

the code to detect the show/hide buttons can be simpler if you give both a common class

Here is the solution based on a PEN you showed me

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const filtered = document.querySelectorAll(".group a");
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".filter-button");
  const toggleContent = () => {
    let filterSelector = [...buttons] // the buttons
      .filter(btn => btn.matches(".inactive")) // that are grey
      .map(btn => btn.dataset.filter); // get their data-filter
    console.log(filterSelector)

    filtered.forEach(anc => { // Hide the links whose classes are are in the filterSelector
      const hide = filterSelector.length > 0 &&
        filterSelector.some(filter => [...anc.classList].includes(filter))
      anc.style.display = hide ? "none" : "inline-block";
    });
  }
  const filter = e => {
    const tgt = e.target; // what was clicked?
    if (tgt.matches(".filter-button")) { // a button?
      tgt.classList.toggle("inactive"); // toggle it
      toggleContent(); // toggle the links
    } else if (tgt.closest(".toggleall")) { // or if (!tgt.matches("toggleButton")) return if you give the buttons a class
      const show = tgt.matches(".toggleall-show"); // show all? 
      const hide = tgt.matches(".toggleall-hide"); // hide all? 
      if (!show && !hide) return; // something else was clicked
      buttons.forEach(btn => btn.classList[show ? "remove" : "add"]("inactive")); // if show, remove all inactive if not, addd all inacctive
      toggleContent(); // toggle the links
    }
  };

  document.addEventListener("click", filter);
});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
.container {
  width: calc(100% - 56px);
  padding: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.toggleall {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  display: block;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgb(70, 70, 70);
}

.toggleall-show,
.toggleall-hide {
  width: 70px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgb(70, 70, 70);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgb(200, 200, 200);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.toggleall-show:hover,
.toggleall-hide:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
}

.filter {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  display: block;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgb(70, 70, 70);
}

.filter-title,
.filter-button {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgb(70, 70, 70);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.filter-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

.filter-button:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.inactive {
  color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

.group {
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  counter-reset: div;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.group a {
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  transition: all 0.5s ease, height 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="platform-controller">
  <div class="filter">
    <div class="filter-title">Filter List 1:</div>
    <div class="filter-button" data-filter="filter0a">Item A</div>
    <div class="filter-button" data-filter="filter0b">Item B</div>
    <div class="filter-button" data-filter="filter0c">Item C</div>
  </div>
  <div class="filter">
    <div class="filter-title">Filter List 2:</div>
    <div class="filter-button" data-filter="filter01">Item 1</div>
    <div class="filter-button" data-filter="filter02">Item 2</div>
    <div class="filter-button" data-filter="filter03">Item 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="toggleall">
    <div class="toggleall-show">Show all</div>
    <div class="toggleall-hide">Hide all</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="group">
  <a class="filter0a filter01" href="www.google.com">Image 1</a>
  <a class="filter0b filter02" href="www.google.com">Image 2</a>
  <a class="filter0c filter03" href="www.google.com">Image 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, your code looks awesome, but I unfortunately couldn't make it work with mine. `Filterbutton`s must be in a class named `filter`, and elements must be in a class named `group` and each are clickable `a` classes. I update the question to make it clearer. Sorry I couldn't imagine that you'd put them all in the same div

Comment: See the update. I use the `.group a` and I removed the dot from the `data-filter="`

Comment: I really don't understand why, but the codes don't hide/show `group a` elements in my codes, although the html part is exactly the same with my example here. I also removed the dots in `data-filter="` but still no luck. I'm still trying to figure out what's the problem. I like how simplified your codes are.

Comment: I found the reasons! First one is, each of my `group a` elements has `display: inline-flex`, and it unfortunately seems to cause a confliction with the js code. Second one is, the div order in my real html is `filter` -> `show-hide` -> `group`, and `<script>window.onload = filter()</script>` part comes right after where `filter` div ends (I need it to be there, not after `group` div). Do you think it's possible to make it work these two details?

Comment: window.onload=filter() is already wrong. Remove the ()

Comment: Actually just remove that statement completely- it is not needed - I’ll add a page load directive and all should work

Comment: Should I remove `<script>window.onload = filter</script>` statement? Isn't possible to make it work like this, please? I'm trying to avoid using page load directives for these kind of practical functions. Since I'm still amateur in webdesign I'm trying to keep my statements together with the used div, so I can figure it out easier when I need to use them somewhere else again

Answer (score 1):

What I've done is wrapped the adding of event listeners into a function, and made sure that function is only called after the document is loaded. This ensures that the listeners make it to the button regardless of when the script is loaded.

I've also added a function, `toggleAll` that accepts a `state` boolean`. If true, all filter-ables will be displayed, and if false, all hidden. Along with this, I changed toggleDisplay's second argument to be a bool instead of a string. I did this because the word "toggle" suggests an on and off state as opposed to any number of possible strings.

Lastly, I added a `.toggled` class to be applied to the buttons. This just removes the color value from being a magic string.

```js
let filterButtons = null;
const allPossibleFilters = [];
// Cannot be const since we need to set it again in toggleAll
let filters = new Set();

/**
 * Initialize the page
 * 
 * Adds the event listeners to the buttons
 */
function init() {
  // Store for later use
  filterButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".filterbutton");

  filterButtons.forEach((btn) => {
    // Add event listeners
    btn.addEventListener("click", filter);
    // Scrape possible filters
    allPossibleFilters.push(btn.dataset.filter);
  });
  document.querySelector('.showallbutton').addEventListener("click", toggleAll.bind(null, true));
  document.querySelector('.hideallbutton').addEventListener("click", toggleAll.bind(null, false));
}

function toggleDisplay(selector, displayState) {
  const elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  const display = displayState ? "" : "none"
  for (const elem of elems) {
    elem.style.display = display;
  }
}

function filter() {
  const filterSelector = this.dataset.filter;
  const show = filters.delete(filterSelector);

  if (show) {
    toggleDisplay(filterSelector, true);
    this.classList.remove("toggled");
  } else {
    filters.add(filterSelector);
    this.classList.add("toggled");
  }

  if (filters.size) {
    toggleDisplay([...filters].join(","), false);
  }
}

/**
 * Toggle the view state of all filter-ables
 * 
 * @param {bool} state Whether or not all filter-ables should be shown
 */
function toggleAll(state) {
  if (state) {
    filters.clear();
    filterButtons.forEach((btn) => {
      btn.classList.remove("toggled");
    });

    toggleDisplay(allPossibleFilters.join(','), state);
  } else {
    filters = new Set(allPossibleFilters);
    filterButtons.forEach((btn) => {
      btn.classList.add("toggled");
    });

    toggleDisplay([...filters].join(','), state);
  }
}

/**
 * Call the init function once the page has finished loading
 */
if (document.readyState != "loading") {
  init();
} else {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);
}
```

```css
.filterbutton,
.showallbutton,
.hideallbutton {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer
}

.group a {
  display: block;
}

.filterbutton.toggled {
  color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
```

```html
<div class="filter">
  <div class="filterbutton" data-filter=".filter01">Filter 01</div>
  <div class="filterbutton" data-filter=".filter02">Filter 02</div>
  <div class="filterbutton" data-filter=".filter03">Filter 03</div>
</div>

<div class="group">
  <a class="filter01 filter02 filter03">This element has filter01, filter02 and filter03</a>
  <a class="filter01 filter02">This element has filter01 and filter02</a>
  <a class="filter01 filter03">This element has filter01 and filter03</a>
  <a class="filter02 filter03">This element has filter02 and filter03</a>
  <a class="filter01">This element has filter01 only</a>
  <a class="filter02">This element has filter02 only</a>
  <a class="filter03">This element has filter03 only</a>
</div>

<div class="show-hide">
  <div class="showallbutton">Show all</div>
  <div class="hideallbutton">Hide all</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. But why do you think `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);` is not enough to initialise things?

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you the snippet. And I'm not entirely sure, to be honest. I figure it has to with the fact that the script could potentially be loaded in after the `DOMContentLoaded` event has already fired. Admitted, I got this concept from [You Might Not Need jQuery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#ready) and didn't question it too much.

Comment: I do think you have a LOT of code for this. Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73402769/295783) for a dryer and simpler version

Comment: I understand that this is verbose, but that is intentional so that the OP can better understand what's happening, and potentially have an easier time extending it if need be. God lines are not good for people who are trying to learn, nor are they good for business in general.

Comment: I see spreads, for ... of and other signs that OP can understand my code. There are no "God" lines only simple well-documented map, filter and some methods